# Remove file extensions from my Php files

Tags: php

How can I remove **.php** extension from php files

**htacess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond
%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

any help is much appriciated, Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at these questions: [My htacess doesn’t remove extension .php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078376/my-htacess-doesn-t-remove-extension-php)   [.htaccess removing of extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23723477/2545927)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If you go to example.com/test/ it will load example.com/test.php

Answer (score 0):

For hat you should define an entry point.

Then you can rewrite your URLs to a parameter of a specified file in that case the index.php.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Then you can filter that parameter in your script and show the correct content.

You have an URL something like:

```
www.example.de/test-test
```

Then everything is rewritten to your index.php. Other possibility if you rewrite to an existing file. You can do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Then you fetch everything behind the slash and call an existing PHP file.

[Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)